# NodeJS stream ReadableState

Tags: node.js, stream

NodeJS documentation mentions about the flowing/non-flowing mode (in `ReadableState`). The following excerpt further explains the different possible states a Readable stream can be in at a time. (https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_three_states)

```
Specifically, at any given point in time, every Readable is in one of three possible states:

readable._readableState.flowing = null
readable._readableState.flowing = false
readable._readableState.flowing = true
```

I would appreciate any references that provides more explanation. I am specifically curious about the characteristics/behavior of each state; and what actions trigger a transition between different states? Furthermore.

- If I am not wrong, in flowing mode: the stream actively generates data, while in non-flowing mode: the stream doesn't generate any data until a `r.read(size)` is called.
- Is there any difference between non-flowing mode and paused mode? `r.isPaused()` is false when `_readableState.flowing == null`.

Answer (score 2):

Best bet is probably searching source/repo on github for 'flowing'.

> Readable streams effectively operate in one of two modes: flowing and
>   paused. When in flowing mode, data is read from the
>   underlying system automatically and provided to an application as
>   quickly as possible using events via the …     explicitly to read
>   chunks of data from the stream. All [Readable][] streams
>   begin in paused mode but can be switched to flowing

https://github.com/nodejs/node/search?q=flowing&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93